# Exclude one value from a field, containing multiple values of a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table, named `group`, in mysql. One of its field is `member_ids` where values are like (2,3,4,5).

I want to use 2,4,5 excluding 3 in one place and 3 excluding others in another.

I am using mysql as a database for PHP. Any idea how to do it with mysql query or php code?

**member_ids:**  `(2,3,4), (2,3,4,5), (1,3,5,7) ...`

There are multiple values in single cell.

Now I want to use all values of 2nd cell except 3 i.e. (2,4,5) to find `email_id` from another table `member`.

I can only use '3' in the query, not the rest i.e. (2,4,5).

I need to find email id of 'id'= 2, 4 and 5 from `member` table.

Comment: Show us your effort first.

Comment: is `(2,3,4,5)` in a single cell ?

Comment: In the above `member_ids` what would be your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

To get all `member_ids` whose value is excluding 3 , you can write

```
select member_ids from group where member_ids != 3;
```

to get all `member_ids` whose value is 3 excluding others, you can write

```
select member_ids from group where member_ids = 3;
```

Comment: those data are in single cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()` like this:

```
SELECT g.member_ids
FROM group g
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', g.member_ids) > 0
   OR FIND_IN_SET('4', g.member_ids) > 0
   OR FIND_IN_SET('5', g.member_ids) > 0
```